# How do I easily package libraries needed to analyze a core dump (i.e. packcore)

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump, hp-ux

The version of GDB that is available on HPUX has a command called "packcore", which creates a tarball containing the core dump, the executable and all libraries.  I've found this extremely useful when trying to debug core dumps on a different machine.

Is there a similar command in the standard version of GDB that I might find on a Linux machine?

I'm looking for an easy command that someone that isn't necessarily a developer can run when things go bad on a production machine.

Comment: Are distribution-specific solutions an alternative? This would be fairly easy to do with debian packages.

Comment: Well sure, but I'm using RHEL so that won't help me much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that does the necessary steps (tested only on RHEL5, but might work elsewhere too):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Take a core dump and create a tarball of all of the binaries and libraries
# that are needed to debug it.
#

include_core=1
keep_workdir=0

usage()
{
        argv0="$1"
        retval="$2"
        errmsg="$3"
        if [ ! -z "$errmsg" ] ; then
                echo "ERROR: $errmsg" 1>&2
        fi
        cat <<EOF
Usage: $argv0 [-k] [-x] <corefile>
        Parse a core dump and create a tarball with all binaries and libraries
        needed to be able to debug the core dump.
        Creates <corefile>.tgz

        -k - Keep temporary working directory
        -x - Exclude the core dump from the generated tarball
EOF
        exit $retval
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
        case "$1" in
        -k)
                keep_workdir=1
                ;;
        -x)
                include_core=0
                ;;
        -h|--help)
                usage "$0" 0
                ;;
        -*)
                usage "$0" 1 "Unknown command line arguments: $*"
                ;;
        *)
                break
                ;;
        esac
        shift
done

COREFILE="$1"

if [ ! -e "$COREFILE" ] ; then
        usage "$0" 1 "core dump '$COREFILE' doesn't exist."
fi
case "$(file "$COREFILE")" in
        *"core file"*)
                break
                ;;
        *)
                usage "$0" 1 "per the 'file' command, core dump '$COREFILE' is not a core dump."
                ;;
esac

cmdname=$(file "$COREFILE" | sed -e"s/.*from '\(.*\)'/\1/")
echo "Command name from core file: $cmdname"
fullpath=$(which "$cmdname")
if [ ! -x "$fullpath" ] ; then
        usage "$0" 1 "unable to find command '$cmdname'"
fi
echo "Full path to executable: $fullpath"

mkdir "${COREFILE}.pack"
gdb --eval-command="quit" "${fullpath}" ${COREFILE}  2>&1 | \
  grep "Reading symbols" | \
  sed -e's/Reading symbols from //' -e's/\.\.\..*//' | \
  tar --files-from=- -cf - | (cd "${COREFILE}.pack" && tar xf -)
if [ $include_core -eq 1 ] ; then
        cp "${COREFILE}" "${COREFILE}.pack"
fi
tar czf "${COREFILE}.pack.tgz" "${COREFILE}.pack"

if [ $keep_workdir -eq 0 ] ; then
        rm -r "${COREFILE}.pack"
fi

echo "Done, created ${COREFILE}.path.tgz"
```

Answer (score 3):

The core file includes the command from which it was generated.  Ideally this will include the full path to the appropriate executable.  For example:

```
$ file core.29529 
core.29529: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/bin/sleep 60'
```

Running `ldd` on an ELF binary will show what libraries it depends on:

```
$ ldd /bin/sleep
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1d3ff000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d3ce00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d3ca00000)
```

So now I know the executable and the libraries needed to analyze the core dump.

The tricky part here is extracting the executable path from the core file.  There doesn't appear to be a good tool for reading this directly.  The data is encoded in a prpsinfo structure (from `/usr/include/sys/procfs.h`), and you can find the location size of the data using `readelf`:

```
$ readelf -n core.29529
Notes at offset 0x00000468 with length 0x00000558:
  Owner         Data size       Description
  CORE          0x00000150      NT_PRSTATUS (prstatus structure)
  CORE          0x00000088      NT_PRPSINFO (prpsinfo structure)
  CORE          0x00000130      NT_AUXV (auxiliary vector)
  CORE          0x00000200      NT_FPREGSET (floating point registers)
```

...so one could in theory write a code snippet to extract the command line from this structure and print it out in a way that would make this whole process easier to automate.  You could, of course, just parse the output of `file`:

```
$ file core.29529  | sed "s/.*from '\([^']*\)'/\1/"
/bin/sleep 60
```

So that's all the parts.  Here's a starting point for putting it all together:

```
#!/bin/sh

core=$1
exe=$(file $core  | sed "s/.*from '\([^']*\)'/\1/" | awk '{print $1}')

libs=$(
    ldd $exe |
    awk '
        /=> \// {print $3}
        ! /=>/ {print $1}
    '
    )

cat <<EOF | tar -cah -T- -f $1-all.tar.xz
$libs
$exe
EOF
```

For my example, if I name this script `packcore` and run it on the core file from the `sleep` command, I get this:

```
$ packcore core.29529
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
$ tar -c -f core.29529-all.tar.xz
core.29529
lib64/libc.so.6
lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
bin/sleep
```

As it stands this script is pretty fragile; I've made lots of assumptions about the output from `ldd` based on only this sample output.

Comment: Now extend your script to handle `dlopen()`ed libraries ;-)

Comment: If we're going to be parsing command output for this I think it would work better to use gdb to get the list of libs, after loading the core dump.  That might even get the dlopen'd libraries.

Comment: you need to add -h to the tar command otherwise symlinks aren't followed and since a lot of libs are actually symlinks - without -h you'll miss some important files. I tried editing the answer but got rejected

Comment: Good catch; I added the `-h`.

Answer (score 0):

I've written [shell script](https://github.com/man0xff/corica) for this. It uses ideas from the answers above and adds some usage information and additional commands. In future I'll possibly add command for quick debugging in docker container with gdb.