# moving core dump from Unix production environment to other development Unix environment

Tags: c++, coredump

One of our application is generating core in production. However core generated does not help much as most of variable values are shown as optimized out / It does not contain much of debugging information.

When we move core from production to development environment gdb fails to load it successfully. I think that is due to dependencies on other libraries on production.

Please let me know how we can move the core from production to development environment without moving remaining dependent libraries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the system libraries on the development environment do not match the system libraries on the production environment, then `gdb` will issue warnings, and may fail to decode the core file.

Answer (score 1):

If the system libraries on the development environment do not match the system libraries on the production environment, then `gdb` will issue warnings, and may fail to decode the core file. You should run `ldd` on your program to find the list of libraries it depends on, and copy those from your production environment to your development environment.

It is usually convenient to copy the dependent libraries into a directory structure that mimics the root directory structure of the production environment (a fake root if you will). Then you can use the `gdb` command `set solib-absolute-prefix` to set it to the path of this fake root for the place to find the libraries.

This question seems related, if not a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557283/how-do-i-easily-package-libraries-needed-to-analyze-a-core-dump-i-e-packcore).

Comment: Thanks, However this copy will involve lot of manual effort. I have once read that we can pack such libraries using gdb command core pack. Are you aware of such command I tried searching for same but could not find much .. It will be real helpful if you can guide me with this ..

Comment: @NoName: I added a link to another question which should help you out.